# Update plan cost in Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a plan named "bronze" which is currently charged at $x dollars per month?

How can I update the price to $y per month and leave the existing customers on $y per month?

Is there a better way than creating a new plan that charges $y?

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/products-and-plans#changing-and-deleting-plans
I'm going to go with creating new a plan, as suggested by the docs.

Answer (score 44):

Plans on Stripe are immutable by design, meaning you can't change the price. However, you *can* delete the plan and re-create it at a new price, with the same name and `plan_id`. Internally Stripe will continue to use the old plan for existing customers.

This will likely get really confusing for you, though, so I would recommend creating a new plan with a new ID.

Reference: https://stripe.com/docs/api/plans/update

Comment: > delete the plan and re-create it at a new price, with the same name and plan_id.


Can you confirm if this still works?

Answer (score 4):

In the Stripe test mode, I have had many customers subscribing to a specific plan with `ID`, I removed it plan, but not customers, then I did create the plan and I noticed the customers were still subscribed to the new plan I just created.

I suggest create your plan no only in your Stripe end but also in your database, but with the same name and ID and also cache them since you hardly changing them at all. This way, if you update the cost in Plans in your database, when you charge users, you can set the charge based on what you have set on your `plans` table in database.

Answer (score 3):

You can't able to change currency, cost or interval of a plan in stripe. In that case, you should create a new stripe plan and subscribe all the belonging users of current plan to the new plan.